# URL rewrite with .htaccess (remove $_GET variables)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have this URL : `https://example.com/beehive_deposit?id=6a23361b37MjE-&owner_cus_id=607dde5711MQ--`

And I want to convert it in this:

`https://example.com/beehive_deposit/6a23361b37MjE-/607dde5711MQ--`

> I am using codeigniter framework in PHP.

I tried something like this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^beehive_deposit/([^/.]+)/?$ beehive_deposit?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

HTML:

```
<a href="/beehive_deposit?id=b5347cb1cdMjE-&amp;owner_cus_id=d6cc12707fMQ--"></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're going about it wrong. The URLs you output to client-side HTML should already be in the "clean" format:

```
<a href="https://example.com/beehive_deposit/6a23361b37MjE-/607dde5711MQ--"></a>
```

And then your rewrite rule becomes (basically):

```
RewriteRule ^beehive_deposit/(.*)/(.*)$ beehive_deposit.php?id=$1&cus_id=$2
```

Comment: I am using codeigniter framework. and it says page not found according to framework's default routing (I guess).

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that. CI has its own expected url structures.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that. Let me edit my question.